# javafx label doesnt show loop result

Tags: java, javafx, label

i created a program to show the result of gcd(greatest common divider) between 2 integer numbers step by step not just the final result in java fx

here is the controller class for it

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    int q, r1, r2, r3, r4, r;


    private Main main;
    private Stage primaryStage;


    public void setMain(Main main, Stage primaryStage) {
        this.main = main;
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextFlow tf;
    @FXML
    private TextArea ta;
    @FXML
    private Text t;
    @FXML
    private TextField field;
    @FXML
    private TextField field1;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String t1 = field.getText();
        String t2 = field1.getText();
        if (t1.isEmpty() || t2.isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Warning");
            alert.setHeaderText("Enter Values");
            alert.setContentText("you have to enter Integer Numbers");
            alert.showAndWait();

        } else {
            try {
                r1 = Integer.parseInt(t1);
                r2 = Integer.parseInt(t2);
                if (r1 < r2) {

                    r3 = r2;
                    r4 = r1;
                    r = r3 % r4;
                    q = r3 / r4;
                    String t = ("r1=" + r3 + "     " + "r2=" + r4 + "       " + "q=" + q + "      " + "r=" + r);
                    String t6 = new String();
                    while (r != 0) {


                        r3 = r4;
                        r4 = r;
                        r = r3 % r4;
                        q = r3 / r4;
                        t6 = "r1=" + r3 + "     " + "r2=" + r4 + "       " + "q=" + q + "      " + "r=" + r;
                        System.out.println(t6);

                    }
                    String t7 = ("gcd=" + r4);
                    label.setText(t + "\n" + t6 + "\n" + t7 + "\n");
                    label.setWrapText(true);
                } else {
                    r = r1 % r2;
                    q = r1 / r2;
                    String t3 = ("r1=" + r1 + "     " + "r2=" + r2 + "       " + "q=" + q + "      " + "r=" + r);
                    String t4 = new String();
                    //this part of code
                    while (r != 0) {


                        r1 = r2;
                        r2 = r;
                        r = r1 % r2;
                        q = r1 / r2;
                        t4 = ("r1=" + r1 + "     " + "r2=" + r2 + "       " + "q=" + q + "      " + "r=" + r);

                    }
                    String t5 = ("gcd=" + r2);
                    label.setText(t3 + "\n" + t4 + "\n" + t5 + "\n");



                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Warning");
                alert.setHeaderText("Values Error");
                alert.setContentText("you can only enter Integer Numbers");
                alert.showAndWait();

            }
            field.clear();
            field1.clear();
        }

    }



    public void close(){
        primaryStage.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){}
    public void changeWindow(){
         main.secondWindow();
    }

}
```

now here is the result when i enter for example 26 15 
here is the result

```
r1=26     r2=15       q=1      r=11
r1=3     r2=1       q=3      r=0
gcd=1
```

but the result should be like this as is it apear in the terminal

```
r1=26     r2=15       q=1      r=11
r1=15     r2=11       q=1      r=4
r1=11     r2=4       q=2      r=3
r1=4     r2=3       q=1      r=1
r1=3     r2=1       q=3      r=0
1
```

so as i said why the label only show the final result of loop not the whole loop like the terminal show it

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Right now there is too much code to give an helpfull answer. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i tried but no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include every step in the `Label`, you need to add something to the final result for every loop iteration. You do not do something like this. I recommend using a `StringBuilder` for this purpose:

```
if (r1 > r2) {
     int t = r1;
     r1 = r2;
     r2 = t;
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (r1 > 0) {
    int temp = r2 % r1;
    sb.append("r1=").append(r2).append("     r2=").append(r1).append("       q=").append(r2/r1).append("      r=").append(temp).append('\n');
    r2 = r1;
    r1 = temp;
}
sb.append("gcd=").append(r2);
label.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your logic runs withing the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT). Asl long as your logic runs the EDT cannot update the screen.

You need to move your logic into a separate Threat that calls the `setText()` method within `Platform.runLater()`

Comment: tnx for ur answer man this sounds great but i dont have time to look it up ill search it once i have time